# Problems displaying buttons containing position:relative and position:absolute

Tags: html, image, button, text

I'm trying to display a vertical list of buttons composed of merged text and images. I'm using position:relative and position:absolute to merge the text with the image.

```
<div class="well">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="assets/launch_item.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
      <div style="position:absolute;padding: 16px 0px 0px 55px;">
       <h5 style="float:left;width:300px;">Option1</h5>
        <a href="http://localhost:3000" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><div class="btn btn-success">Go</div></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative">
    <img src="assets/launch_item.png" style=position:absolute;"/>
    <div style="position:absolute;padding: 16px 0px 0px 55px;">
      <h5 style="float:left;width:300px;">Option2</h5>
      <a href="http://localhost:3000" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><div class="btn btn-success">Go</div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The combined button turns out OK but there seem to be problems arranging the buttons in the parent window. As seen on the image above, only one of the two buttons gets displayed. Moreover the button gets slapped on to the existing window instead of "fitting into it". How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Provide a Fiddle code for this with your images, CSS and Jscript for the issue part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float` inside the `h5` and control it with the `position`, as you have already made a `relative` positioning for the parent `Div`, so I suggest creating the elements inside it with `absolute` positioning like what you have done for the rest of your elements. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/c6n7q/2877/).

The Updated Code:

```
<div class="well" style="position:relative;">
  <div style="width:300px;">
    <img src="assets/launch_item.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <div style="position:absolute;padding: 8px 0px 0px 55px;">
      <h5 style="width:300px;position:absolute;">Option1</h5>
        <a href="http://localhost:3000" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;position:absolute"><div class="btn btn-success">Go</div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:300px; left:305px; top:0; position:absolute;">
    <img src="assets/launch_item.png" style="position:absolute;"/>
    <div style="position:absolute;padding: 8px 0px 0px 55px;">
      <h5 style="width:300px;position:absolute;">Option2</h5>
        <a href="http://localhost:3000" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;position:absolute"><div class="btn btn-success">Go</div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT - 2**

Usually for menus, `UL` and `LI` play a vital role. Considering your code with a `position` has no problematic effects, just that list items are more useful for these stuff. Providing you with a [new solution with list items as vertical menu](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh95V/). This is like a further reference for you to know about the creation of menu styles with list items. Hope this helps.

- [This](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/291_vertical_menu/demo/index.html) resource was used during the research for the list items creation with vertical menus.

Hope this makes your work easier. :)

Comment: Did this but the end effect is still the same: only the second button is visible. Updated code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tromanow/faRk7

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can accept it by a green tick and upvote, if not, let me know for queries/issues for the same. - @Ya.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately it doesn't produce the desired result. The first button displays correctly, the second one is about quarter in size which I really don't get. Also the well div is not resized correctly.

Comment: Eventually I got it to look like I want http://jsfiddle.net/tromanow/WVL5n/ but I was hoping there would be an easier way with the buttons being displayed one below each other and automatically fit into the well without me having to calculate the widths and the coordinates. Upvoted you for giving me a hint.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. But I am hungry for more and more, coz I love CSS ;) - @Ya. One more hint. Pls find in the updated answer as **EDIT - 2**. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow:hidden` to the div with class `well` so that the buttons will be fitted into that parent div.

Comment: All it does is chops off the part that doesn't fit.